# C Program, Switch menu endless loop

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, infinite-loop

Okay It now loops correctly but when you give it an input e.g. '2' it just goes to the default case.

```
 print_Menu() {
        while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("=============================================\n");
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("=============================================\n");
        printf("1. Do stuff\n2. Do more stuff\n3. Do even more stuff\n4. Quit\n");
        printf("Choose an option: ");

        scanf(" %s*", &selection);


        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                /*do your thing for option 1*/
                printf("thing 1\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                /*do your thing for option 2*/
                printf("thing 2\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                /*do your thing for option 3*/
                printf("thing 3\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                /*do your thing for option 3*/
                printf("quiting app\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf(" Invalid selection\n");
               // print_Menu();
                break;
        }
      }
```

Comment: By incorrect input you mean an integer that is not in the range 1-4, or do you mean something that is not an integer?

Comment: Do you really want to call the function recursively on the default case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
scanf("%*s");
```

in the `default` case to clear the invalid character(s) from the input buffer.The `*` tells `scanf` to scan a string and then discard it.

`scanf` fails to get an integer and returns 0 when you enter any other thing other than an integer. This data does not get consumed by the `scanf` and hence, remains in the `stdin`.When `scanf` is called for the second time,it sees the character which you typed in earlier and then again fails to read an integer.This will then result in an infinite loop

Comment: @Sparky3295 And don't call `printMenu()` recursively.

Comment: @Sparky3295 ,Also specify the return type before the function definition.(I think you need `void` there)

Comment: Okay that worked, but now when I enter an option it just goes straight to the default.

Comment: @Sparky3295 , What did you enter?

Comment: when I entered an option e.g 1, it would just call the default case and not case 1. I've used a while loop now so that I don't recursively call print_Menu() and that seems to do what I want it to.

Comment: @Sparky3295 ,I told you to add the `scanf` in my answer in your `default` case .I never told you to change your `scanf`! Use the `scanf` which you had before editing your question

Comment: @CoolGuy I misunderstood sorry. I have done that and it now works correctly.

Comment: @Sparky3295 ,There is,however,one defect in the code...When you enter any integer that dosen't have a case,then you will have to enter any other data for the `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(1!=scanf("%d", &selection)){
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    selection = -1;
}
```